# Migrations as a cluster initialisation phase

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I would like to run some initialisations/migrations when Akka cluster is starting. Actually I would like it to be fully running but not accepting commands/events from "outer world".

Right now I have a singleton actor which keeps track of already applied migrations and runs pending ones one by one. However, nothing prevents actors from receiving events initiated by other workflows. That leaves a possibility of concurrent changes which must be avoided.

I think about introducing global flag for the mode cluster is currently in. When it is set to `Migrating` services accepting requests from outer world should reject or buffer the requests until mode is changed back to 'Running'.

I do not have much experience with Akka in general and Akka clustering in particular. Maybe someone could give me an advice, how I better solve the issue of migrations/initialisations.